# Dividing a triangle into 4 different triangles - proof

Tags: proof-writing, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> [image: Sorry for the inaccurate drawing but that was all I could do on Jamboard.]

I apologize for the rough and wobbly diagram but that was all I could achieve on Jamboard!
ABC is a scalene triangle and so is QPR.
The question is: "Prove that the perpendiculars from A to BC, B to CA, and C to AB meet at one point, labeled H".

Comment: What does your problem have to do with the $QPR$ triangle? And the title is not relevant to the text. Then the question is what have you tried? Where are you stuck? What are you allowed to use? Note that questions showing no effort tend to be voted down and are closed.

Comment: There are several parts to this question and I have only posted one part so that is why triangle QPR may be irrelevant to this question.  Normally, if you look at my other posts, I include a pretty detailed explanation as to what I have tried but I was very confused as to what to start with in this question and honestly haven't tried anything as I don't know where to start! @Andrei

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/geometry-home/triangle-properties/altitudes/v/proof-triangle-altitudes-are-concurrent-orthocenter